# macOS-like app switching in Plasma 5

Tags: kde, window, plasma, application-switcher, plasma-5

In macOS, you can cycle through *applications* (note: not windows) by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. However, when <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>bing in Plasma 5, you cycle through all windows of all applications, which can get overwhelming when having multiple instances of one app.

I would like to be able to alt-tab between apps just like in macOS (switching between windows of the same app is already solved by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is possible:

Go to system settings and then:

Window Management --> Task switcher --> Tick only one window per application

[image]

Comment: I decidedly hate this behavior...not all of us love OSX. Thanks for showing us how to turn this *off*.

Comment: @smaudet that is why I love linux and especially Kde, you can adjust it to your liking, and we do not need to like the same things :-)