# ALT+TAB no longer groups windows under applications in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, application-switcher, 19.04

After installing Ubuntu 19.04, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> no longer groups windows under the same application. Instead it cycles through all windows irrespective of which app it belongs to. In Ubuntu 18.10 it worked differently (and better in my opinion) such that <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switched between apps, and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd> (key above <kbd>TAB</kbd>) switched between windows of the same app. How can I achieve this setup in 19.04?

**NOTE:** <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd> still cycles through windows of the same app, but I cannot use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> first to select the app from the shorter list of apps (compared to the list of windows), so then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> loses much of its power if you have many windows open.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to the [release notes for Ubuntu 19.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaves differently than before:

> alt-tab handling now switches windows by default. Switching applications by default can be done with super-tab

The image below illustrates what <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does:

[image: Alt+Tab]

And <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between applications with each application's windows available below:

[image: Super+Tab]

The following image shows the default "switch" options in *Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation*:

[image: Default keyboard options for switching windows/applications]

Comment: @pomsky I added an image of the relevant part of the screen. I'll now see if I can change anything there from the built-in GUI (without resorting to gsettings or dconf-editor).

Comment: @pomsky looks like I'm not the best person to check that out because I don't remember what Ubuntu 18.10 did in this regard. I'm mostly on Kubuntu where I have **1** `Alt`+`Tab` to list applications with `Tab` to move to the relevant application (keeping `Alt` pressed all the while) > then **2**, with `Alt` still pressed using the "`" key to tab between windows of the same application. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134083/macos-like-app-switching-in-plasma-5

Comment: What you described is also the behaviour in GNOME in older releases and what OP is trying to achieve I believe. In the settings window (as in your screenshot) can't you switch the combinations for 'Switch applications' and 'Switch windows'? Then it'll be same as what you described.

Comment: That works. I first had to set an "intermediate" keybinding for Switch Applications otherwise, I'd have the same keybind for two separate shortcuts.

Answer (score 9):

All keyboard shortcuts including <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can be managed in the  **Settings** / **Keyboard Shortcuts** menu.

I liked the style in Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME, where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch Applications.
In Ubuntu <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches applications by default, but you can change this to your liking.

A shortlist, with the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS defaults. NB! Subject to change between versions.

- **Switch applications (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)** - Only navigate between applications. The last highlighted application window is selected by default - Great when you are <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>'ing between your browser and Terminal window.
- **Switch windows (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)** - Switch between all your open windows, regardless of which application it is.
- **Switch windows directly (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>)** - Switch back/forth between your two latest windows on one press, or cycle pressing repeatedly, regardless of application. Reminds me of GNU Screen's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.
- **Switch windows of an application (<kbd>Super</kbd>+*key above* <kbd>Tab</kbd>)** - Switch between windows of the current application only. As I have multiple Terminal and browser windows at all times I love this one. That's <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd> (pipe) on my keyboard. YMMV.

And just in case,

<kbd>Super</kbd> is your [Windows key / Mac key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)).

Answer (score 1):

Alt-TAB is one, for the workspace apps, but
Control-Alt-TAB switches between all app from all workspaces
(dconf, marco settings)